# Use BeautifulSoup to find specific tag based on the text the tag covers?

Tags: html, beautifulsoup

Say I have the following HTML:

```html
<div class="test">
<a class="someclass" href="somesite.com"> LINK </a>
<a class="someclass" href="othersite.com"> IMAGE</a>
</div>
```

is there a way to get the `href` from all a-tags encapsling the text "LINK" i.e in this example `somesite.com` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is that you're trying to find text which has whitespaces. You can use `Regular Expressions` to ignore the whitespaces and do a `find` on the `text`

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import re

html = '''<div class="test">
<a class="someclass" href="somesite.com"> LINK </a>
<a class="someclass" href="othersite.com"> IMAGE</a>
</div>'''

soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'html.parser')
regex = re.compile(r'\s*%s\s*' % 'LINK')
results = soup.find("a", text=regex)
print(results['href'])
```

**Output:**

`somesite.com`

An alternative way is to preform `find_all` & then loop through results & compare the text using `text.strip()`

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
    
html = '''<div class="test">
<a class="someclass" href="somesite.com"> LINK </a>
<a class="someclass" href="othersite.com"> IMAGE</a>
</div>'''

# Find href by text 'link'
soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'html.parser')
results = soup.find_all('a')
print([x['href'] for x in results if x.text.strip() == 'LINK'])
```

**Output**

```
['somesite.com']
```

Comment: Yeah - that's my approach so far aswell. I wonder if there was something like a CSS selection or something else that could pull it. Thanks though

Comment: To avoid the double looping over the soup

Comment: @CutePoison - to avoid double looping you can use regex